# Maps having the right lifting property against cofibrations of compact spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories

I would like to know the properties of the maps that have the right lifting property against cofibrations of compact spaces. By definition, they are acyclic Serre fibrations, but I would hope to be able to say more about them. In particular, how close are they to being Hurewitz fibrations? Plus, are they the fibrations of a model structure on the category of compactly generated weak Hausdorff spaces?